# Implementing Toggle Full Screen menu item

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I created this code basing on JavaFX tutorial:

```
    final String change[] =
    {
        "Full Screen", "Exit Full Screen"
    };
    final MenuItem fullScreen = MenuItemBuilder.create().text(change[0]).build();

    fullScreen.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            fullScreen.setText((fullScreen.getText().equals(change[0])) ? change[1] : change[0]);

            if (fullScreen.getText().equals(change[0]))
            {
                primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
            }
            else
            {
                primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
            }
        }
    });

    view.getItems().add(fullScreen);
```

I need to improve it by using switch statement in which I want to set the text and `setFullScreen`. Is there any more elegant way to implement this?

EDIT: This code works but the implementation is very ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check real status rather then text
2. Use binding to update text and you will not need to care about initialization and fullscreen mode changed by other methods

   ```
   MenuItem fullScreen = new MenuItem();

   fullScreen.textProperty().bind(
        new When(primaryStage.fullScreenProperty())
             .then("Exit Full Screen")
             .otherwise("Full Screen"));

   fullScreen.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
       @Override
       public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
           primaryStage.setFullScreen(!primaryStage.isFullScreen());
       }
   });
   ```